# Date picker empty error

Tags: datepicker

I got a form that posts some value to another page. I want alert for datepicker inputs when i post form if they are empty. I have been trying to solve it but couldn't. It is simple but my brain just stopped i think. Code is below. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee95P.png

This is the link of screenshot of my form. Maybe this can help you.

```
        <form id="form-2" class="form-3" method="POST" action="rezervasyon-aşama-2" >
                            <label style="margin:2px 70px; font-size:16px;" >Rezervasyon Formu</label><br>
                                <div style="padding:5px 5px;">
                                    Check-in Tarihi:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <input id="datepicker-example7-start" type="text" name='tarih1' >

                                    </script>

                               </div>

                              <div style="padding:5px 5px;">
                                 Check-out Tarihi: 
                                <input id="datepicker-example7-end" type="text" name='tarih2' >
    </div>
<input  TYPE="submit" class="button" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Rezervasyon Yap"  >

    </form>
```

when i click input file, the datepicker shows up. So i want a alert if i submit empty. Sorry for my English :) Thanks for helps.

Comment: Do you want an alert when the user doesn't select a date, or when a user attempts to submit the form without a date?

Comment: Both can be fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the attribute from ID to NAME -- it was an oversight on my part.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        $('input[name^="tarih"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                alert("Your alert here"); //Whatever error message here.
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6tp9P/3/

Comment: It is not working mate. Still posting empty input to another page without giving me any error :(

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I was reading your source thinking the name was the ID for some weird reason.